# Tree-views in table layout panel and get values dynamically c#

Tags: c#, windows, treeview, tablelayoutpanel

I have multiple treeviews in the table layout panel - C# windows application.

Each cell consists of Treeview or dropdown or textbox. I can get the value of textbox and dropdown but I am unable to get the selected node of multiple Treeviews in the table layout panel.

below my code.

```
        int rows;
        int column;

        rows = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount;
        column = tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount;

       


        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                Control value = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(j, i);
                //here i got specified treeview but i can't get refernce. getting error
                string controlName = value.Controls.Owner.Name;
                //here i got error i am unable to get treeview selected text
                string seletedvalue = controlName.SelectedNode.Text;
                MessageBox.Show(controlName);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the control, but you are not checking what type of control it is, and you are not casting it.  So it stays as a general control and not a TreeView.  And only the TreeView has nodes.

You can also simply the selection of the specific control that you want.

```
foreach ( TreeView tv in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<TreeView>()) 
{     
    string seletedvalue = tv.SelectedNode.Text;
    MessageBox.Show(tv.Name + " " + seletedvalue);
}
```

Comment: it Works...! but i have multiple controls in the table layout panel like textbox and dropdowns also. I want to check and get data like from the first cell to the last cell and need to store the data.